# React & Redux - Handling mutation of state after call API in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need some help from you about my case in react redux call action and get state reducer value. The new state reducer value after call action can't access in useEffect.
This is my actions function:

```
export const checkItem = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get(mainUrl+'/api/cekitem')
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ITEM_CHECK,
        payload: res.data
      })
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data || 'Terjadi kesalahan', err.response.status || 404))
    });
};
```

And this is my reducer function:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ITEM_CHECK:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload.data,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I try to call the action in my app.js file inside useEffect.

```
export const TheItemModule = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [itemABC, setItemABC] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const itemRedux = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.items)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(checkItem);
    
    if (itemRedux) {
      // hope this is called after itemRedux trigered by checkItem
      // or some method for manipulated item
      // example:
      setItems(true) 
    }
  }, [checkItem]);

  render() {
    return (
      {itemABC && <div>Cek ABC & 123</div>}
    )
  }
}
```

Note: That example is simplified from my real case. I hope this example clear.

When checkItem called in useEffect, the itemRedux in useEffect not triggered again, so itemABC state not updated.
Maybe someone can help me to give an insight.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch action is async, so the selector does not have a value when you run that code. I think you could create the new `useEffect` to listen to the changes of `itemRedux`, like so:

```
export const TheItemModule = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [itemABC, setItemABC] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const itemRedux = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.items)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(checkItem);
  }, [checkItem]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (itemRedux) {
      // hope this is called after itemRedux trigered by checkItem
      // or some method for manipulated item
      // example:
      setItems(true) 
    }
  }, [itemRedux])

  render() {
    return (
      {itemABC && <div>Cek ABC & 123</div>}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: oh, so the solution is simple. useEffect can be called more than once. Thank you for save my time.